# OnCreateView method in Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

[fragment reminder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMSLX.png) - current problem

This current class that I am using called Fragment Reminder is used to display a list of the medications that have been entered. However this class before was a Fragment and I decided to change it to an Activity and the method which displays the list called onCreateView is unused now. When I click on that button to run this class the screen goes dark for some reason. Now that this class is an Activity the onCreateView cannot be used since that is for a Fragment. What should I change that to so I can create the list.

FragmentReminder:

```
package com.example.junai.mrtest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.view.View.GONE;


public class FragmentReminder extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList al;
    private List list=new ArrayList();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView lv;
    TextView tv;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public void receiveData(ArrayList al)
    {
        this.al=al;
        list.add(al.get(0));

    }


    //data for customlist
    private String desc[] = {};


   // @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setTitle("Medicine Reminder");
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reminder, container, false);
        fab=(FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        lv=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.rem_lv);
        tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reminder_tv);

        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(this);
        list=db.getAllReminders();

        if(list.size()==0)
        {
            lv.setVisibility(GONE);
            return v;
        }

        tv.setVisibility(GONE);

        adapter = new CustomList(this,list,desc);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //***Customised list view add***********************************************************************
       /* CustomList customList = new CustomList(getActivity(),list, desc);
        lv.setAdapter(customList);*/

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You Clicked "+list.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //addReminderInCalendar();
                Intent in=new Intent(FragmentReminder.this,MedRemInfo.class);
                in.putExtra("id",list.get(i).toString());
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        //***************************************************************************

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in=new Intent(this,AddReminder.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

}
```

fragment_reminder.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.junai.mrtest2.FragmentReminder">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/reminder_tv"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="No Reminders to show, Add a reminder.."
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rem_lv"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.junai.mrtest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by junai on 20/03/2018.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn_addReminder, btn_reminderinfo;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_addReminder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addReminder);

        btn_addReminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddReminder.class));
            }
        });


        btn_reminderinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reminderinfo);

        btn_reminderinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentReminder.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

CustomList:

```
package com.example.junai.mrtest2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List names;
    private String[] desc;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, List names, String[] desc) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_medinfo, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.desc = desc;

    }
    String color_hex[]={"#ff4000","#0000ff","#003EFF","#5C246E","#8B668B","#CD2990","#D41A1F","#FBDB0C","#FF6600"};
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //********************************************************************
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_medinfo, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(getItem(position));
        String firstLetter = null;
        //get first letter of each String item

            Log.d("String",getItem(position));
            String str=getItem(position);

            firstLetter=String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
           // firstLetter.toUpperCase();
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
            // generate random color
            //int color = generator.getColor(getItem(position));

            int color = generator.getRandomColor();
            int pos= new Random().nextInt(color_hex.length);
            color = Color.parseColor(color_hex[pos]);
            Log.d("Color",""+pos);

            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .buildRound(firstLetter, color); // radius in px

            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        return convertView;
        //***********************************************************************
       /* LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_medinfo, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.medname);
        TextView textViewDesc = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        textViewName.setText(names.get(position).toString());
        textViewDesc.setText(desc[position]);
        image.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        return  listViewItem;*/
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.medimage);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.medname);
            Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/georgia.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(typeface);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Activity use onCreate not onCreateView method

Comment: Two things to take care:
1. Make sure you are not calling db operations in the main thread. So, move the database loading call to an AsyncTask or some other background operation and once you get the result, set the adapter in the main thread. Hopefully this will remove the "Black Screen" issue.
2. If you are using Activity, use the oncreate() method.

Comment: yep replaced with onCreate and now works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've refactored your code:

```
public class FragmentReminder extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList al;
    private List list = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView lv;
    TextView tv;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public void receiveData(ArrayList al) {
        this.al = al;
        list.add(al.get(0));

    }


    //data for customlist
    private String desc[] = {};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_reminder);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rem_lv);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reminder_tv);

        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        list = db.getAllReminders();

        if (list.size() == 0) {
            lv.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        tv.setVisibility(GONE);

        adapter = new CustomList(this, list, desc);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //***Customised list view add***********************************************************************
       /* CustomList customList = new CustomList(getActivity(),list, desc);
        lv.setAdapter(customList);*/

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You Clicked "+list.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //addReminderInCalendar();
                Intent in = new Intent(FragmentReminder.this, MedRemInfo.class);
                in.putExtra("id", list.get(i).toString());
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, AddReminder.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

}
```

You need only to move the code to `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateView()` and  also you don't need to access the recently inflated view V to do `findViewByID`, all you have to do is `setContentView()` beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for refactoring the code, it works now but the only problem I have is that the screen only displays for the number of items I have in the list. For example I have 2 medications in the list and its like the black screen I mentioned before but the list is like a popup and the size of that screen basically wraps the content in that list.

Comment: your actiity should be full screen

Comment: I've included the main activity which shows how I open the fragment reminder

Comment: I'm sorry, I've looked into your code, it all looks fine. The FragmentReminder activity should be full screen, not a popup. Are you sure you replaced the code, it looks like a FragmentDialog to me

Comment: I've replaced the code too and it wont change, i've included the customlists java code. Thats how that list is created, although I dont think the problem is there

Comment: I just checked the manifest and wow it was a mistake on my part, apologies. I had this:                                                                                              <activity android:name=".FragmentReminder"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>                              That is why it was like that, just removed it and now it works fine. Thanks for all your help!